# Run android service after android app closed by user

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi how can I start android service when app closed? I use xamarin.android and need a service that run after application closed by user.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the scenario which you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want update token from app to server...if user closed the app,token can not updated,so I need service that start after app closed